# Adding Hyperlink in subgrid

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I want to add Hyperlink for each row in subgrid. What I am looking is I want to display a invoice number as a link. When user clicks on that it should open a external window. Already tried with Hyperlink field available Dynamics. But its comes with https://..  I don't want to show the URL inside the grid.

Regards

Saman

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your using the Out of the Box sub grid on the Web Interface / UCI, in which there isn't an out of the box way to render a clickable external URL.

Is the invoice in CRM, if it is a record in CRM and it can be related to the subgrid record, adding the lookup field to the view will provide a clickable link.

Your other option would be using a custom UI to build your subgrid, like Kendo or building a PCF.

Though I don't see any existing PCFs in the gallery that do this (https://pcf.gallery/categories#grid) you could likely use one as a starting point.

Comment: @chis fernando, Thanks. The entity here I am referring is a Virtual entity. Adding additional lookup field may not possible,

Comment: Is this in a model driven app?  Have you looked at creating a PCF?  I've done something similar with a Kendo UI based web resource in the based (opening a Sharepoint library) but MS recommends creating PCFs going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I used javascript to do it.

First, write script to search DIV tag that contains the value of each field's row,
then get its innerHTML value to add hyperlink tag <a .... and add back.

Second, add this script to "Web resources" of solution in PowerApps

Then, adjust the view of the table that need to add hyperlink by open View editor in Classic view and change properties of the field. It'll have dialogue shows up to select Web resources and input function name written in javascript